Power BI Publish to Power BI Service Using Direct Query Failing
I have created several Power BI reports and am using DirectQuery connections to a SQL database to pull the data. When I try to publish these reports to the Power BI Service I get the following error:
To publish this report ask your power bi admin if they will allow directquery connections to power bi datasets
I am the admin on Power BI and have my license, however do not see anywhere to turn these settings on.
Thanks
Searched admin portal to enable query - didn't find any options.
Change to import mode and publish is successful.

If you are an admin for Fabric (the overarching platform under which Power BI falls) you should be able to navigate to the admin portal at https://app.powerbi.com/admin-portal?experience=power-bi and then go to:
tenant settings > Allow DirectQuery connection to Power BI semantic models
If you enable the above then publishing should work for your report. If you do not have this option in the admin page then there is something wrong with your permissions and you may need to go to Azure > Entra ID and add the Power Platform Administrator role to your use
